# GTK: change a range of text style in textview

Tags: fonts, gtk, gtktextview

I am writing a C application in Ubuntu using gtk+2.0.

I have a textview to disply chat messages. Every message comes below the time it's sent.

What I want to do is use different font style(e.g. color) to display them.

I find these font chooser and color chooser but I haven't found how to use them yet.

Can someone give me some advice, or better, examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text shown in a text view is represented by a [`GtkTextBuffer`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html). To change the appearance of one segment of the text buffer, you create a [`GtkTextTag`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkTextTag.html), for example using [`gtk_text_buffer_create_tag()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-create-tag), set the font and colors as you like and apply the tag with [`gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-apply-tag) on a range of the text buffer identified by start and end iterators.

It may be worth to have a look at the Gtk+ manual, which has a [section](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/TextWidget.html) that describes how the different components work together.